# Sub labelling of an object

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, labels, labelling

First timer in image processing - Pardon my cluelessness.
Is there a concept of sub labeling in objection identification? I want to label a person and sub label "eye" of a person and train a model to detect if the person's eye is open or closed. i.e do not look for floating eyes in a frame - only look for eyes on a person.
Does it improve inference efficiency?  How do I do it with LabelImg?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [face segmentation](https://github.com/topics/face-segmentation) is what you are looking for.  This one looks pretty promising at first glance: https://github.com/zllrunning/face-parsing.PyTorch

> Does it improve inference efficiency?

Improve efficiency compared to what? Inference efficiency will probably vary with model size. Compared to vanilla facial recognition, inference will probably be much *less* efficient because segmentation models are typically larger.

> How do I do it with LabelImg?

LabelImg is a tool for annotating image datasets. You can use it to create your own dataset for training/fine-tuning but the use of LabelImg is independent of the segmentation model.